# How we get conversations messages from Facebook Using PHP Sdk v5.0

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

start from beginning,i fetched Facebook Page id,access token,user access token,user id user emails,means i have lot of information about a facebook user profile and pages details,now i want to fetch conversations messages between user and page,i have all privilege to read message and i get messages through graph api explorer but its quite different to implement with programmatically.
so if anyone have knowledge how to get messages with php sdk code then please update me. thanks in advanced.

Comment: Quick Google search reveals the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/conversations) for the Pages API.

Comment: hello DarthGualin i use page_id with conversation but it gives me   array output that return page access code.

Comment: I am able to login with facebook and post anythings on facebook,but if i want to fetch user message then what i do please explain programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
   'app_id' => '{app-id}',
   'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
   'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
]);

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken({access-token});

$responsePosts = $fb->get('me?fields=feed{id,message,full_picture}');

$postsNode = $responsePosts->getGraphNode();

var_dump($postsNode);
```